# Interfacing with "API" that only takes raw SQL: Node / pSQL sanitization without prepared statements or parameterization?

Tags: sql, node.js, database, postgresql, sql-injection

I am working with an "API" provided by a client's ERP. They do not have actual endpoints, rather a REST endpoint that you can send raw sql queries to, that they then execute. To make matters even worse, *they only recently upgraded to https*.

I am writing some Node cloud functions to interface with this system. There will be two roles working with this product, and I need to prevent the role with less permissions to fire unwanted queries in the application when they are searching with specific parameters.

For filtering, I can just check if the values are in an array of allowed terms, but with a search I am not quite sure how to approach this. My general opinion has always been to use parameterized statements, but that is not an option here as I can't actually establish a connection to their database. I also saw some posts where people suggested wrapping the strings in dollar signs since the underlying DB is PostgreSQL, but I could not find anything in the documentation for this purpose.

I was also thinking about only allowing alpha-numeric characters, but this seems like a potentially weak approach. If anyone knows of any libraries or ideas for dealing with this situation, I would greatly appreciate it.

I tried looking for a Node library or piece of documentation that could help this situation, but I could not find anything relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I found this interesting post around the question: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/172297/sanitizing-input-for-parameterized-queries.
To summarize it, doing data sanitization(more like general validation) is always good idea but it will not necessarily guarantee that query will be safe. Directly running queries without parameterized statements will be still quite a big risk even if you find some great library for cleaning data to make it SQL safe.
Instead try to think of ways to not run user input directly. Add some kind of mapper in between which will accept some filter codes and translate it into SQL values. For example if I had delivery company and wanted to filter all deliveries with status delivered, I would use mapping like this:

```
const status_code = "DELIVERED"
const statusMapper = {DELIVERED: "delivered"(value to filter in sql)}
```

And if my mapper does not find the exact match, return error or empty result and don't run the query at all. If its search bar, try to identify most frequent search keywords and build mapper for that. Obviously it will not be too accurate, but still better than having risk of sql injection, especially if you work with sensitive and important data(I assume you work with company's internal data since you integrate with ERP).

Comment: Thanks Edward, I ended up using this approach for sorting, but it gets trickier when I need to start worrying about matches for a first name for example.

Comment: @LukeWeston Well lets say if its first name, you can do validation to only have characters from A-Z. Your best bet would be to use specific logical validations for each field, whatever makes sense for your context to minimize the risk